# AVR ATtiny24 timer compare interrupt not working

Tags: c, arduino, avr, attiny

I'm driving a clock using timer0 to keep track of seconds passing. Originally, I was using an ATtiny85 and it worked fine, but when I switched to the ATtiny24, the interrupt seems to reset the clock to initial value.

I know the interrupt is triggering because when I comment out the timer0 settings and ISR, I'm able to change the hours and minutes on the clock (When timer0 is active, the clock just resets back when I use the buttons to change the time)

For reference here's the code for the timer0 settings and the ISR

**timer0 settings**

```
  cli();
  TCCR0A = 0x00;
  TCCR0B = 0x00;
  
  TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02) | (1 << CS00); // prescaler to 1024
  
  TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01); // set to CTC mode

  OCR0A = 124; //reset on 124
  TCNT0 = 0;
  
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A); // enable interrupt on OCR0A match
 
  initOutput();
  sei();
```

**ISR**

```
ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect){

    cli();
  
    if(ticks == 124){

      ticks = 0;
      
      seconds++;
      displayUpdate = 1;
      
      if(seconds > 59)
      {
          minutes++;
          seconds = 0;
          displayUpdate = 1;
      }
        
      if(minutes > 59)
      {
        hours++;
        minutes = 0;
        if(hours == 12){buff[8] ^= 1;}
      }
            
      if(hours < 10 && digits[7] == 128)
            {
                  digits[7] = 0;
              
            }else if(hours >= 10 && digits[7] == 0){
                digits[7] = 128;
            }
            
            if(hours > 12)
      {
          hours = 1;
      }
    }else{
      ticks++;
    }
    sei();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have not found a mistake in your code but after i checked the datasheet i found a difference between ATtin25 and ATtiny85. In ATtiny24 [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc8006.pdf) the interrupt vector is called `TIM0_COMPA` and in the ATtiny85 [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf) it is called `TIMER0_COMPA` (Interrupt Vectors, both on page 48). So try to rename the ISR to:

```c
ISR(TIM0_COMPA_vect)
{
  // ...
}
```

Sorry, i do not have the controller here to check if it works.

Comment: Additional note: when triggering an unassigned interrupt, the default behaviour is to jump to the reset vector.  The consequence is that heap variables gets re-initialized.  This is probably why the clock resets with an attiny24 using the incorrect interrupt name.